# detect and remove the Frame Busting Code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

how to detect and kill the Frame Busting Code in javascript :

The typical source code for a framekiller script is:

if (top!=self) top.location.href=self.location.href;

Comment: if the frame is your domain simply remove the code

Comment: But, for my requirement to display the html pages in an iframe .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, if the `iframe` contains a page served from a different domain, you won't be able to stop it.  In newer browsers, there will be a `sandbox` attribute which might do the job (as there is an option to `allow-top-navigation`), however, most browsers do not recognise it yet.